# Raw SQL vs OOP based queries (ORM)?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, orm

I was doing a project that requires frequent database access, insertions and deletions. Should I go for Raw SQL commands or should I prefer to go with an ORM technique? The project can work fine without any objects and using only SQL commands? Does this affect scalability in general?

**EDIT**: The project is one of the types where the user isn't provided with my content, but the user generates content, and the project is online. So, the amount of content depends upon the number of users, and if the project has even 50000 users, and additionally every user can create content or read content, then what would be the most apt approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say it's better to try to achieve the objective in the most simple way possible.
If using an ORM has no real added advantage, and the application is fairly simple, I would not use an ORM.
If the application is really about processing large sets of data, and there is no business logic, I would not use an ORM.

That doesn't mean that you shouldn't design your application property though, but again: if using an ORM doesn't give you any benefit, then why should you use it ?

Answer (score 8):

If you have no ( or limited ) experience with ORM, then it will take time to learn new API. Plus, you have to keep in mind, that the sacrifice the speed for 'magic'. For example, most ORMs will select wildcard '*' for fields, even when you just need list of titles from your `Articles` table.

And ORMs will aways fail in niche cases.

Most of ORMs out there ( the ones based on *ActiveRecord* pattern ) are extremely flawed from OOP's point of view. They create a tight coupling between your database structure and class/model.

You can think of ORMs as [technical debt](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TechnicalDebt.html). It will make the start of project easier. But, as the code grows more complex, you will begin to encounter more and more problems caused by limitations in ORM's API. Eventually, you will have situations, when it is impossible to to do something with ORM and you will have to start writing SQL fragments and entires statements directly.

I would suggest to stay away from ORMs and implement a [DataMapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) pattern in your code. This will give you separation between your *Domain Objects* and the *Database Access Layer*.

Comment: @tereško comeback to the PHP room man. I missed having to hate you. Plus, I need help with something.

Comment: I think this answer is good to answer something like, "Please help, I suck at learning and I either want to jump into ORM Blind, or continue working with TSQL Like I'm used to."  In that case, of course this is a good answer.  But if you use an ORM, and create an N-Tier application with common abstractions that create persistence ignorance, then there isn't an issue.  This is a horrible thing for a developer to do if the cost/benefit isn't there.  But then again, this isn't a developers job.  If you're the architect, stop QQ'ing and go learn how to architect.  That applies to non-ORM also.

Answer (score 2):

For speed of development, I would go with an ORM, in particular if most data access is CRUD.

This way you don't have to also develop the SQL and write data access routines.

Scalability should't suffer, though you do need to understand what you are doing (you could hurt scalability with raw SQL as well).

Comment: What if the CRUD access is very frequent, and I have a very large database? Doesn't the ORM act as a memory-hogger? Even caching wouldn't be useful then I believe (correct me if I'm wrong)...

Comment: @c0da - It depends on th ORM, but normally, they would _help_ with performance.

Comment: @Oded I've edited my question, please check that and now answer... I'd appreciate that...

Comment: @c0da - My answer doesn't change :)

Comment: @Oded I notice that you used the word **normally** in your previous comment... What does that mean?

Comment: @c0da - Just that they _are_ an abstraction and if not used correctly _can_ cause problems. Like any other code.

Answer (score 1):

If the project is either oriented : 
- data editing (as in viewing simple tables of data and editing them)
- performance (as in designing the fastest algorithm to do a simple task)

Then you could go with direct sql commands in your code.

The thing you don't want to do, is do this if this is a large software, where you end up with many classes, and lot's of code. If you are in this case, and you scatter sql everywhere in your code, you will clearly regret it someday. You will have a hard time making changes to your domain model. Any modification would become really hard (except for adding functionalities or entites independant with the existing ones).

More information would be good, though, as : 
- What do you mean by frequent (how frequent) ?
- What performance do you need ?

**EDIT**

It seems you're making some sort of CMS service. My bet is you don't want to start stuffing your code with SQL. @teresko's pattern suggestion seems interesting, seperating your application logic from the DB (which is always good), but giving the possiblity to customize every queries. Nonetheless, adding a layer that fills in memory objects can take more time than simply using the database result to write your page, but I don't think that small difference should matter in your case.

I'd suggest to choose a good pattern that seperates your business logique and dataAccess, like what @terekso suggested.

Comment: Edited the question... Please go through it... :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on timescale and your current knowledge of MySQL and ORM systems. If you don't have much time, just do whatever you know best, rather than wasting time learning a whole new set of code.

With more time, an ORM system like Doctrine or Propel can massively improve your development speed. When the schema is still changing a lot, you don't want to be spending a lot of time just rewriting queries. With an ORM system, it can be as simple as changing the schema file and clearing the cache.

Then when the design settles down, keep an eye on performance. If you do use ORM and your code is solid OOP, it's not too big an issue to migrate to SQL one query at a time.

That's the great thing about coding with OOP - a decision like this doesn't have to bind you forever.

Answer (score -1):

I would always recommend using some form of ORM for your data access layer, as there has been a lot of time invested into the security aspect. That alone is a reason to not roll your own, unless you feel confident about your skills in protecting against SQL injection and other vulnerabilities.

Comment: Let us suppose that I am able to manage the Security perspective very well... So, Raw SQL would work fine then? On one hand (as pointed out in comment on above post), ORM provides me with caching and easy scalability (as I would have to write less and less code if scalability is being done). But on the other hand, if large amount of data is being processed in the database, the ORM fails to an provide what it was really meant for (i mean fast caching and everything else)...

Comment: security aside, ORM's have a ton of functionality that you may or may not need. You would need to weigh the functionality you need vs. what you can develop. Bottom line is that ORM's are typically free and development is not!