# What is the best choice to get result from database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

What is the best choice to get result from database? (in server side DAO)

1. Using query syntax (like JOIN, WHERE)
2. Using programming business logic

   - ex)

     1. Get data using simple query (SELECT userId FROM customer)
     2. use Programming Code (User user = query.result)
     3. execute another query using code variable value
        {query.execute("SELECT * FROM order WHERE userid = ?",[user.id])}

Comment: In most cases you would go with a JOIN, Rule-of-thumb: Database queries inside loops are seldom a good idea.

Comment: Databases are designed to do this. Why would you possibly want to fetch every result, and then per record you find, execute another query? (Let's say you have 1000 users, that means 1001 queries instead of 1. Which do you think performs better?)

Comment: Possible duplicates: - [Using an ORM or plain SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494816/using-an-orm-or-plain-sql) - [Are there good reasons not to use an ORM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194147/are-there-good-reasons-not-to-use-an-orm) - [Raw SQL vs OOP based queries (ORM)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834540/raw-sql-vs-oop-based-queries-orm)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using an ORM or plain SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494816/using-an-orm-or-plain-sql)

Comment: @wast I don't see what this question has to do with ORM?

Comment: @Ivar I think he thought of ORM on 2. so he is asking what is the best practice.

Comment: He is talking about server side DAO so I doubt he actually thinks of using an ORM. His steps also don't really point in that direction.